# Compile time error in header file

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Origin code of error

```
static int pthread_setcancelstate(int state, int *oldstate) {
    sigset_t   new, old;
    int ret;
    sigemptyset (&new);
    sigaddset (&new, SIG_CANCEL_SIGNAL);

    ret = pthread_sigmask(state == PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE ? SIG_BLOCK : SIG_UNBLOCK, &new , &old);
    if(oldstate != NULL)
    {
        *oldstate = sigismember(old,SIG_CANCEL_SIGNAL) == 0 ? PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE : PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

**error: passing         'sigset_t' to parameter of
      incompatible type 'const             sigset_t *'; take the address
      with &                           ...= sigismember(old,SIG...**

I am compiling a program but above error is generating.

I am learning c but I am stuck at above error .

Comment: Did you carefully read documentation of [sigismember(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigismember.3.html) ? Read it more and take the habit of reading documentation of every function that you use.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message *tells you* to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error suggests you need to pass address of old as argument to the function `sigismember` as below:

```
*oldstate = (int *) sigismember(&old,SIG_CANCEL_SIGNAL) == 0 ? \ 
                                PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE : PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE;
```